# User-friendly URLs

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I currently have the following setup for my paging model: `/pages/6-about`

```
class Page < ActiveRecord::Base 
  def to_param
    "#{id}-#{permalink}"
  end 
end
```

I would like the URL to be `/pages/about`. What is the best solution? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

So you change your

```
def to_param
  permalink
end
```

And then implement a

```
def self.from_param(value)
  find_by_permalink(value)
end
```

in your page model.

In your controllers you would then need to

```
def show
  @page = Page.from_param(params[:id])
  ...
end
```

Answer (score 0):

There are not much informations on your question.
There are several routes to doing that but it all depends on what you are doing.

If the number of pages is fixed you can just keep a static hash table that keeps track of name <-> id.

```
 private static readonly Dictionary<string, int> PagesDict = new Dictionary<string, int>(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase) { { "about", 6 }, { "home", 1 }, { "xxx", 2 } };

///<summary>Gets a page id by a string name. Returns -1 if page doesn't exists.</summary>
public static int GetPageId(string name)
{
    int result;
    if (!PagesDict.TeyGetValue(name, out result))
        return -1;
    return result;
}
```

If you need a read-write dictionary instead, you can use a ConcurrentDictionary, but of course, this dictionary is not stored anywhere and will be lost if the dictionary is not loaded from something like a DB table or an XML.

If your pages are dynamic and loaded from a DB you need a table on the DB that gives you an id by a name. You can index the table by name then, and the query should be quite fast.
If you want to reduce the number of access on DB you can implement a (quite complicated) cache system using concurrent dictionary.

Edit-

The amount of information required to restore the ID must be greater or equal the amount of information the ID field can store :)

I mean...

If permalink is not unique, there is no way you can obtain an id from it.

If permalink field is unique it is the same thing as an ID, it is a string id.
Then you can write a query that given a permalink will return you an id.

If you can restore an ID from a unique couple of fields, for example, permalink and fieldX, you can write a query where permalink='about' AND fieldX='XXX'

Comment: Hi Thanks for the Quick response. sorry for not adding extra information i thought it lay in the to_param's setup.

The page content is coming from a DB
Following fields - ID,Title,permalink,body